# List comprehension in python for a multiline for loop

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

need a help on list comprehension on following scenario code.

```
a = "e00-5"
x = []
for i in range(4):
    tmp = a+"-"+str(i)
    x.append(tmp)
```

I tried the following but failing with this error

```
x = [ tmp = a+"-"+str(i) for i in range(4)]
File "<stdin>", line 1
x = [ tmp = a+"-"+str(i) for i in range(4)]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
enter code here
```

Can anybody suggest what gonna wrong here.. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `tmp =`

```
x = [ a+"-"+str(i) for i in range(4)]
```